# Unwanted characters in in nltk3?

Tags: nlp, python-3.3

I am currenlty working in a natural processing language project, and I scrapped several text from the web. I have worked out from some code fragments here from this site.

```
f = open(new_file, "w")     #arquivo para escrita do texto processado

with open(txt_file,  'rb') as in_file:

    for line in in_file:
        line = line.lower()         # troca tudo para minusculas
        if  re.search('\S', str(line)):
            line2=line
        phrases_list = re.split('[!?.,;:&()]+',  str(line2))         #separa as linhas pelos pontos

        for phrase in phrases_list:
            word_list = []
            # testa para ver se esta na lista de stopwords

            for word in phrase.split():         #separa as linhas em palavras
                if  word in contractions:
                    new_word =contractions[word]
                    if new_word not in stopset:
                        word_list.append(new_word)
                else:
                    if word not in stopset:
                        word_list.append(word)

            new_phrase = ' '.join(word_list)        # converte a lista em uma string

            # limpa o texto e salva cada frase linha por linha
            clean_phrase = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z\s]+", '', new_phrase).strip()
            if clean_phrase !='':
                f.write("%s\n" % clean_phrase)
f.close()

process_text(file_name,  caminho+"textoprocessado3.txt")`
```

In textoprocessado3.txt there appear things like:

> b xexxceuropeanxexxd
>   b every real peoples revolution
>   b bourgeois revolution  displayed xexxcbrilliantxexxdn

How can I get rid of these unwanted characters, such as "b" at the beginning, "n" at the end or xexxc...xexxd?

Comment: First you have to check whether you're reading the file in the correct encoding. Can you post the full input file somewhere? And what are the criteria for cleaning, why are you cleaning out the characters/strings (even when they're noise) when they are part of your data?

Comment: Well, input text is a little bit longer. I pasted a fragment of it in: http://ur1.ca/ocabp As you can see, I have split the whole text in lines in order to construct n-grams to be processed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the issue has nothing to do with NLTK. The code you posted doesn't even show any use of NLTK.

The main problem is that you are opening the input file in binary mode ('rb') instead of text mode ('rt', 'r', or just skip it, since both 'r' and 't' are the default). Opening a file in binary mode gives you bytes – but you want text, so you need the text mode.

Let's look at an example: A file with a single line of text:

> It’s

So 4 characters (plus a final newline). Note that the thrid character is not the ASCII apostrophe, but a typographical quote (Unicode character U+2019). The file is encoded in UTF-8.

If you read this in text mode, everything is fine:

```
>>> with open('example.txt', 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as f:
...     text = f.read()
... 
>>> text
'It’s\n'
```

It's crucial to have the right encoding, because the default encoding might not be the right one. It's a good guess to always try UTF-8 first, because if it's not the correct encoding, it will cause a decoding error.

However, if you read in bytes, this is what you get:

```
>>> with open('example.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     bytes_ = f.read()
... 
>>> bytes_
b'It\xe2\x80\x99s\n'
```

That's how the encoded text was written to the disk, using 3 bytes for the typographical quote character. When you call `str()` on this, you get a representation string, where everything "special" is escaped, eg. newlines:

```
>>> str(bytes_)
"b'It\\xe2\\x80\\x99s\\n'"
```

And then you remove everything but the ASCII letters a through z, and whitespace, which means you remove the backslashes and digits:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z\s]', '', str(bytes_))
'bItxexxsn'
```

And that's exactly what happened on line 60 of the fragment you posted on ur1.ca.

Long story short: **Use text mode when reading text.**

Comment: Thank for your help, Lenz! It worked fine, and I have learned a little bit more about Python 3.